# How do ethical values shape one's aesthetics?

Tags: ethics, aesthetics

I have been struggling through an idea for the past several months regarding the order of values and its influence upon art. It started with a quick tour of an online art gallery showcasing Rafael, Michelangelo, Da Vinci, Rambrant etc.. and I was taken back by the shared symbolic architecture upon which many of these scenes were painted. They seemed to all have Greco-Roman pantheons and the Judeo-Christian narratives as a means to convey very human emotion and forms. Now I am aware that many of the artists mentioned were working in the time of the rebirth of ancient themes and literature, but I can't help but think the shared symbolic pallet of Christianity across the continent at their time influenced the way their art appeared and was received.

I have been wrestling with the idea that the highest position of value a person can set their thinking to is their ethical conduct, which affects the rest of their thinking. This is why we can appreciate something but know it is wrong first, this being evidence that the aim of ethics is forefront but not commanding as much an influence over the individual like the base instincts of pleasure and survival.

However, if the ethical landscape had enough of a shared foundation in the christian narrative, then perhaps their art would have the aesthetic of their ethic. The same way art has remained thematically similar since the age of post modern thought, their aesthetic is modeled upon the landscape of their ethical values. Perhaps this is why the christians of today favor classical art and frown upon the forms produced by post modern and modern artists and the way the further away from traditional values one strays the more away from classics their taste in art becomes.

In which school of Philosophy can I find more guidance and literature on this subject of values as it pertains to Aesthetics?

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: Deduced? A deduction is an escapable conclusion, and I'm not sure there's a deductive proof to show that ethics is the "highest" application of value, whatever high means in this sentence. Have you investigated works in ["axiology"]?(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiology) and ["value theory"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/value-theory/)?

Comment: Questions like are generally recognized as having no authoritative answer, and we do Q&A, not debate. So, questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I have edited the question to fit guidelines, Thanks @JD

Comment: The basic Christian based ethic is conservative and always reflects the dogmatic theme of the era and formulates an ethic on strict conformance to canonical law. That way the given leadership of whatever religious group under consideration can control the thoughts, behaviors and wallets of the faithful. Modernist and postmodernist art reflects the development of the individual becoming free from the mind control of religious authority. Pure religion relies on nothing more than the aware individual, guided by 'reason'. This unerring guidance leads to true piety and communal love. Spinoza (TTP).

Comment: In order to recapture the aesthetic dimensions of moral experience, one needs a continuity principle that enables reflection on morality to be true to experience.https://responsejournal.net/issue/2016-08/article/problems-intersection-aesthetics-and-ethics

Comment: There is a Universal force which give a relation between aesthetics and ethics , we call it "beauty of holliness"https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691632803/beauty-and-holiness